# Moving data into a variable gives invalid instruction operands

Tags: assembly, masm32

I know that I'm not allowed to move data between two variables, but even after trying to move it through a register, I still get this error

```
mov eax, array
mov giveVal2, eax
mov eax, array+8
mov giveVal1, eax
```

Comment: Did you declare `array` as holding `dq` elements?  EAX isn't the same size as a qword, and MASM makes you write `mov eax, dword ptr [array]` if you really want to use a different size than memory.  If those are double-precision floats like your last question, use `fld` / `fstp` to copy them.  (Or `movups xmm0, [array]` to load 16 bytes at once, and arrange your other two variables so you can do a 16-byte store.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, thank you, my code got really messy, and I have tried to put 64-bit value into a 32-bit register

Comment: Next time, make sure your Stack Overflow question is a [mcve], that someone could actually assemble and see the same error message. (It doesn't have to *do* anything or even be runnable as a complete program, since you have an assemble time error).  This is missing the declaration of `array`.  I was only able to guess `dq` from the `+8`, and your previous questions.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, will take a note from that. Sorry for an incorrect question formatting